# Office Open XML Format file creation

Tags: ms-office

i want to open a new xl sheet thru ofice open xml format. and how to export the datatable records to that xl sheet without loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bala. You will have to be a bit more detailed about what you want to do, and which platforms you can and want to use, where you want to export data from/to, what is the programming angle of it all (do you want to use scripting?) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.extrememl.com/index.php/knowledge-center/tutorials/working-with-excel-tables/populating-a-table-from-a-data-source) that shows how to inject the contents of a DataTable into a template Excel worksheet. It uses the [Microsoft OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0) in conjunction with [ExtremeML](http://www.extrememl.com/), an open-source extension library.

The accompanying tutorials in the series demonstrate how to perform similar operations using other data sources, such as arrays, DataSets and Linq.